# How to drag nodes with children in d3 circle packing?

Tags: d3.js, nested, position, drag

I have been trying to drag in d3 packed nodes using this code as a basis https://codepen.io/MrHen/pen/GZQOPW. Unfortunately I can't find a method to use so that when a node with children is dragged around it's (visible) children move with the parent. I use this function to drag circles around:

```
var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
.on("drag", function(d, i) {
  d.x += d3.event.dx;
  d.y += d3.event.dy;
  draw();
})
```

I the example above for instance I want to be able to drag the nodes on layer 1 (light blue) and when I do this their children change their position so they stay (visually) in the borders of their parents.

Thank you!

Comment: You only set the drag event on the leaf nodes (those without children).  So, do you mean you want to drag the parent when the child is moved?  You problem description states it the other way around.

Comment: Hello @Mark, Thank you a lot for the answer. What I want to do is to drag the children when I move the parent. I I set the drag on the parent the parent moves, but the children don't.

Answer (score 2):

First remove the `pointer-events: none` on the root and middle nodes.  Then set yourself up a little recursion to walk a node's descendants and update their position:

```
  function recurOnChildren(d) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    if (!d.children) return;
    d.children.forEach(c => {
      recurOnChildren(c);
    });
  }
```

And call from your drag handler:

```
  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d, i) {
      recurOnChildren(d);
      draw();
    })
```

Running code:

```js
var margin = 20,
  diameter = 960;

var color = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([-1, 5])
  .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var pack = d3.layout.pack()
  .padding(2)
  .size([diameter - margin, diameter - margin])
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.size;
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter)
  .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")");

d3.json("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mbostock/7607535/raw/695f8ed6298c06a946406c707200a1f6b21875d8/flare.json", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var focus = root,
    nodes = pack.nodes(root),
    view;

  function recurOnChildren(d) {
    d.x += d3.event.dx;
    d.y += d3.event.dy;
    if (!d.children) return;
    d.children.forEach(c => {
      recurOnChildren(c);
    });
  }

  var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
    .on("drag", function(d, i) {
      recurOnChildren(d);
      draw();
    })

  var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      return d.parent ? d.children ? "node node--middle" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root";
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d.children ? color(d.depth) : null;
    });

  var text = svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .style("fill-opacity", function(d) {
      return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
    })
    .style("display", function(d) {
      return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    });

  var node = svg.selectAll("circle,text");

  svg.selectAll(".node").call(drag);

  d3.select("body")
    .style("background", color(-1))

  draw();

  function draw() {
    var k = diameter / (root.r * 2 + margin);
    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + (d.x - root.x) * k + "," + (d.y - root.y) * k + ")";
    });
    circle.attr("r", function(d) {
      return d.r * k;
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```